# Android - How to add more items in bottom ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I work on a Galaxy Note 2 and Android. 
I want to add 4 text items in the bottom ActionBar of an Activity.
But, after adding the third one, the fourth doesn't appear on the screen in Portrait Mode but appears in the top ActionBar in Landscape Mode.

I've tried all of the Android options on the items and always the same result.

How can I add 4 with the basic ActionBar or an other one ?

Thanks.

edit:

My XML menu file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/it1"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="1"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/it2"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/it3"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="3"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/it4"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="4"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: please post your xml file..

Answer (score 0):

Using android:showAsAction="always" with text only doesn't work as Android seems to use a fixed size for action items that have text only regardless of its length. This is (of course) not a documented feature but I tested it on a Note II, a One X and a Galaxu Nexus, all running JB, so it seems to be (at least) a JB issue.

My recommendation would be to use icons instead of text which works for more than three action items

Comment: You are right. I tested it on a Galaxy Note II but the same behavior of on other Jelly Bean devices. They seem to set a fixed size for action items when there's text involved regardless how long the text is. What helps though is using an icon instead of text which is recommendable anyway.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, unfortunately :( Thanks, anyway.